# Invalid Syntax coming up for while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

```
if rounds == 20:
    response2 = input("Ok the game has now finished. I hope you had fun playing because I sure did. If you want, type 'restart' to play again.")
    if response2.lower() == "restart":
        start_game()
    elif playerpoints >= 10:
        print("Wow you did quite well. Your score is " + str(playerpoints)
        (img = pygame.image.load('TrophyImage.png'))

        (pygame.init())
        (size = (1000, 1000))
        (screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size))
        (done = False)
        (clock = pygame.time.Clock())

        while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get(): 
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                    done = True
            screen.fill(WHITE) 
            screen.blit(img,(0,0))
            pygame.display.flip() 
            clock.tick(60)
        pygame.quit()
```

I've already defined the colors at the beginning of the code so they aren't the issue.

I'm trying to load a picture of a trophy which I have saved. When I run this program, it says *invalid syntax* but doesn't highlight anything. The I beam pointer just goes to the "while not done" so I'm guessing therein lies the problem.

Comment: try while (not done):

Comment: You never properly closed the `print` line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the parenthesis around the assignments. `(X = Y)` needs to be `X = Y`. Because assignments are not permitted in expression contexts.

```
>>> (X = Y)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    (X = Y)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> X = Y
```